# Ring of polynomials in $\mathbb Z_{10}$ linear zero divisors

Tags: polynomials

I'm new here so apologies if I am not clear enough. I am trying to find the zero divisors of the form $ax + b$ in $\mathbb Z_{10}$. Specifically, I need to find the values of $b$. I know that $2,4,5,6$ and $8$ are zero divisors in $\mathbb Z_{10}$ but I am not sure how to translate these into linear divisors.

As all these zero divisors are the product of $5$ and itself (apart from $5$), can I just multiply $2x + b$ by $5$ to get $5(2x + b) = 5b \pmod{10}$? Then I would be left with $0,2,4,6$ and $8$.

I'm also looking to find the units in $\mathbb Z_{10}$ but I don't think there are any. I don't know how to show this, though.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, James

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things 
about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if 
you write what your thoughts 
are on the problem and include your efforts (work in progress) in 
this and future posts and in what context you have encountered the problem; this will prevent people 
from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers 
at the right level.
This site uses
[MathJax formatting](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)

Comment: Thanks JKnecht. I will take your advice on board and be more clear in future. I will also use the formatting tool you have posted. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $ax + b$ is a zero divisor in $\mathbb Z_{10}[x]$, then $(ax+b)(cx+d)=0$, which implies $ac=0$, $ad+bc=0$, $bd=0$. In particular, $b$ is a zero divisor in $\mathbb Z_{10}$ because if $d=0$, then $c\ne0$ and $bc=0$.

Conversely, every $b$ that is a zero divisor in $\mathbb Z_{10}$ is a zero divisor in $\mathbb Z_{10}[x]$.

Comment: Thanks guys, that all makes sense and is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Units**

As you note, $0,2,4,5,6,8$ are zero divisors, hence cannot be units. We are left with $1,3,7,9$. $1$ is clearly a unit: it is its own inverse. Same holds for $9$: $9\cdot9=81\equiv1\pmod{10}$. As for $3$, note that $3\cdot7=21\equiv1\pmod{10}$. So $1,3,7,9$ are the units of $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$.

**Linear zero divisors**

As for the zero linear divisors, here are a few points.

- Note, as noted in the other answers, that if linear polynomial is a zero divisor, $(ax+b)(cx+d)=0$ for some $c,d\in\mathbb{Z}_{10}$.
- Now, the product expands to $acx^2+(bc+ad)x+bd$. So we must have:

  $$ac=bc+ad=bd,$$

  hence both $b$ and $a$ must be zero divisors.
- Now suppose $a,b$ are zero divisors, so there exist $c,d$ such that $ca=bd=0$. Is $bc+ad=0$? Not sure, but if we multiply it by $cd$ it will surely be. So if we take the polynomial $c^2dx+cd^2$, multiplied by $ax+bd$ it is 0.
- Of course, this opens another problem: is at least one of $c^2d,cd^2$ nonzero?
- If both $c$ and $d$ are even, their product will not be divisible by 10, hence $c^2d,cd^2$ will both be nonzero.
- If $c,d$ are both $5$, then $c^2d=d^2c=25\not\equiv0\pmod{10}$.
- If they are an even number and $5$, then the same will be true of $a,b$. So $ax+b$ will be either of the form $2kx+5$ or $5x+2k$, with $k$ an odd non-$5$ and nonzero number.
- Well, naturally I am assuming $a,b\neq0$, or at least one of them. If exactly one of them is nonzero, it means we have $2kx$ or $2k$, which is a zero divisor since multiplied by $5$ it gives 0$ $_, or we have $5x$ or $5$, which are zero divisors since $2\cdot5=10$_.
- What about the $2kx+5$ and $5x+2k$? For the first case, I must have $2kc=5d=2kd+5c=0$. For $2kc$ to be 0, $c$ must be $5$. For $5d=0$, $d$ must be $2m$. So $2kd+5c$ is $25+4km$. But that cannot be zero, since we would need $4km\equiv5\pmod{10}$, which is impossible since it is even. And I bet the case $5x+2k$ is dealt with in much the same way.

**Bottom line theorem**

$ax+b$ is a zero divisor if and only if one of the following holds:

1. $a,b$ are both zero divisors of the same parity;
2. $a=0$ and $b$ is a zero divisor;
3. $a$ is a zero divisor and $b=0$.

Comment: Thanks guys, that all makes sense and is very much appreciated.